# How to deselect criteria VBA autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, criteria, autofilter

I need to filter out criteria in my macro. There are many criteria in that column but I simply need to deselect one. So instead of listing out the many positive options, is there a way to just filter a single option out?

Comment: Did you try to record a macro and do required steps manually and then check generated VBA?

Comment: **1.** Retrieve the visible items after the filter and store them in an array. **2.** Remove the unwanted item from the array **3.** Re-Apply the filter.